# Согласование имен существительных

Tags: согласование

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в каком падеже должно быть им. существительное "погашение" в таком предложение: Возможно ли выделение долей в квартире между членами семьи пропорционально вкладу каждого в погашении (погашение) ипотеки.
Как правильно согласовать: вклад во что или в чем?

Answer (score 1):

Словарь: вклад *во что* Значительное достижение в области науки, культуры и т.п.
Погашение ипотеки нельзя считать чем-то сопоставимым с наукой, культурой, то есть чем-то глобальным. Слово "вклад" не подходит.

На слух согласование "вклад в погашение" перебивает "вклад в погашении" (оно почти не используется, судя по Нацкорпусу, нашёл лишь один пример). Но погашение не является какой-либо областью деятельности, поэтому "в погашение" не очень звучит (будто это что-то выдающееся). В плане этого "вклад в погашении" (*вклад в плане погашения*) лучше. Но такое согласование используют так: *вклад в области/сфере...*

Предложение нуждается в редактировании.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно — «погашение», но я не очень представляю, как это объяснить. Пропорционально вкладу во что — это вопрос винительного падежа, а «погашении» стоит в предложном падеже. Как-то так.